# Hood "config.json" values

Tags: postgresql, go

I have some problems with documentation for `hood`, there no explanation about what supposed to be in `config.json`.
I've tried:

```
{
  "development": {
    "driver": "postgres",
    "source": "my_development"
  }
}
```

but I have the error:

```
hood db:migrate
2014/06/23 12:53:14 applying migrations...
panic: missing "=" after "my_development" in connection info string"
```

Comment: Given that there's no concrete example (from my quick skim), a number of outstanding issues (35) and no activity since October 2013, I'd suggest looking at another library as it sounds like you're just starting out. I'd recommend either sqlx (http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) or gorp (https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp) - gorp being an ORM.

Comment: indeed there is not activity in the last months. Move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [hood](https://github.com/eaigner/hood) documentation :

> The driver and source fields are the strings you would pass to the sql.Open(2) function.

So the `driver` value should be `postgresql` (for your example), and the `source` value should be either a list of `key=value` or a full connection URI (like described in the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)).

Some examples (from [here](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq)) :

- `postgres://pqgotest:password@localhost/pqgotest?sslmode=verify-full`
- `user=pqgotest dbname=pqgotest sslmode=verify-full`